# BackupBuddy won't let me Export a Sub-Site from within my Wordpress MultiSite install. Even though it should

Tags: wordpress, export, backup

I have been using backupbuddy for some time, and have done this many times. Then i took a break for a month or two, and now it won't let me export a Sub-Site from my Wordpress Multisite install!?? I've tried deactivating plugins, uninstalling and re-installing BB, updating everything, and when i try and export the sub-site it always gives me the same message:

"**Export Unavailable for Main Site**

The main Network site cannot be exported as it is tied to the Network. It can only be backed up from the main Network Admin. All other subsites can be exported for importing into the same Network (aka Duplicate), another Network, or as a standalone site. See the BackupBuddy Multisite Knowledge Base for additional information."

Why does it think this is the "Main Network Site"... it's not. Can i set which site SHOULD be the main network site?

I'm at the end of my rope here.

Any helpful suggestions are welcome...
~eric